# Проблема с компоновкой при вызове функции Fortran из кода C/C++

Tags: c++, c, компоновщик, fortran

Я пытаюсь вызвать функцию написанную на Fortran из кода на C. Но при компоновке получаю ошибку "undefined reference".

Пример функции на Fortran в файле fort.f90:

```
FUNCTION CULC(A,B) RESULT(SUM) BIND(C,name='CULC99')
REAL A,B,SUM
SUM = A + B
RETURN
END
```

Основной код на C, файл hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern float CULC99(float *a, float *b);

int main() {
    float a = 10; float b = 10;
    float c;
    c = CULC99(&a,&b);
    printf("%f", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Компилирую для Windows с помощью *gfortran* и *g++* в среде Cygwin64 (решив проблемы с недостающими библиотеками)

[image: undefined reference]

Проверял имя функции в объектном файле с помощью objdump, имя совпадает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю чего не хватает.

Пробовал делать тоже самое (вызывать функцию из другого объектного файла) для чистого C, всё прекрасно компонуется.

Comment: Не стоит путать С и С++. А если уж собираете как С++, то указывайте линковку `extern "C" float CULC99(float *a, float *b);`

Comment: Кстати, вы уверены, что REAL в фортране сответствует типу float (4 bytes), а не double (8 bytes)?

Comment: @avp, вполне возможно что не соответствуют, но меня сейчас не это интересовало. Собралось и с float/REAL. Дальше я буду применять готовый код Fortran с оболочкой для C.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно заметил @user7860670

> Не стоит путать C и C++

Проблема оказалась в том, что я перепутал компиляторы gcc и g++.

После добавления `extern "C"` компилятор g++ нашёл вызываемые функции.

Возможно gcc справиться с компоновкой при использовании `extern`, но я не смог это проверить, т.к. нужно подключать недостающие библиотеки, а у меня уже нет сил на это, после 3-х дней войны с компоновщиком =(

Comment: В подобных случаях немного разные объявления для C/C++ пушут так -- `#ifdef __cplusplus \n extern "C"\n { \n#endif \n float CULC99(float *a, float *b); объявления др. функций  #ifdef __cplusplus \n } \n#endif`